# Getting a segmentation error when printing my array of strings

Tags: c++, arrays, string

Hello all c++ noob here,
For my homework in c++ I must create a program that inputs 5 cities and prints them in order and reverse order by the users choice using arrays and seperate functions. The homework requires that you use all these functions to operate.  The program runs fine until I enter o or r for reverse order. I get a segmentation error. I think I am printing or passing the strings incorrectly.

Here is my declaration of my array function

```
void displayInOrder (string o[5]);
```

Now here is my function with the executable code.

```
void displayInOrder (string o[5])
{
    cout << "Here are the cities in order: " << endl;
    cout << o[0] << " " << o[1] << " " << o[2] << " " << o[3] << " " << o[4] 
         << endl;   //the error seems to lie somewhere in here and the same 
                    //in the reverse function
}
```

Now in the main I am calling the function like this.

```
displayInOrder (&cities[5]);
```

I think I am either calling the function incorrectly, declaring it wrong, or printing it wrong. It's been a while since I programmed in C++ and I am a bit of a noob. I appreciate any help anyone has to offer.

Comment: I suspect a mere fix to `displayInOrder (cities);` should resolve it. Hard to say, you didn't provide a [mcve].

Comment: Before wasting your time here to provide us with incomplete examples, you should invest some in improving your [_debugging skills_](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/).

Comment: C style array does not work that way, use `std::vector` or `std::array` instead.

Comment: Also consider to use a `const std::array<std::string,5>&` or at least a `const std::vector<std::string>&` as parameter type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `displayInOrder()` function is expecting a pointer to an the whole array. Instead, you passed a pointer to `cities[5]`. This has two problems:

1. It's a pointer to a specific element, not the whole array.
2. The last element of the array is `cities[4]`, so you're accessing outside the array bounds.

You should call the function this way:

```
displayInOrder(cities);
```

There's no need to use `&`, an array variable automatically decays to a pointer when used as a function argument.

Comment: Thank you so much! You are a life saver my friend. I understand now.